# Flare VM installation requires another Windows Verison

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, version

I am currently trying to install Flare VM (https://github.com/mandiant/flare-vm) on my laptop. FlareVM tells me to use a VM and also a tested Windows version (17763, 19045, 20348).
How can I set one of these versions up on my laptop as a vm and which product key for Windows do I need? (I prefer to use the key again when I don't need FlareVM anymore).

Thank you.